# How to add paging to GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

How do I add paging to this GridView?

**C#** code:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**Error**

`Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index`

Comment: asp.net code:  AllowPaging="True" 
               OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"  PageSize="5" . I have added the above statements in asp:gridview. I am getting the following error while running the application "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index " How to solve this?

Comment: show me your `Page_Load` code plz..

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
      
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           
        }
    }

Comment: what is that,,show me your full Page_Load code and paste it on your question..not on comment.

Answer (score 0):

You again you need to in page index changing event. Here you have not written that.

See [the link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67520/GridView-Paging-and-Sorting)

```
myGridView.DataSource = your datasource here;
myGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow paging is very simple.Call `PageIndexChanging` event of grid view like

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = Your datasource here;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Hope it works for you..

Comment: first set pageindex and then bind your gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I do is I write the page index code and then call the actrual bindmethod of the grid after that:

```
myGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
BindmyGridView();
```

where

```
private void BindmyGridView()
{
myGridView.DataSource = lst; //where lst is the datasource
myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Also have you gone through these links:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038808/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-asp-net)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470346/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-value)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pageable data source. The simplest way is to just use an `SqlDataSource`.
Also, note that `PageIndex` is zero-based.

If you're using a `List` or a `Collection` etc., it needs to be big enough, which is a nice waste of space. Basically, if you're doing manual paging, and you're using a `List`, you're going to have to create the `List` as big as the full record count of your result, and only fill in the proper page. Not very practical, and quite wasty, but it's simple enough.

Apart from creating your own pageable data source, there's also another, nicer way. You can use the `AllowCustomPaging` property to specify that you're *already* passing paged data. Just set `VirtualItemCount` to the record count, and pass just the one page in the `DataSource` and call `DataBind` as usual. That should do :)